# Vertical spacing in enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, line-spacing

I’m using enumerate to make lists for the reader to fill in.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to have 8mm of vertical space between two consecutive dotted lines, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Schweinebacke sorry about the MWE, I should have known better. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with `enumitem`:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, before=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8mm}]
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
    \item \dotfill
\end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bernard , that’s exactly what I was trying to do!